# Because analyzer >=2.0.0 depends on meta ^1.7.0 ... (because myP depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and analyzer 2.0.0, version solving failed)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-channel

Is there any other way to resolve this issue other than going on the dev channel (or than using analyzer <2.0.0)? I once made a poor, time consuming experience with the dev channel which is why I would prefer sticking with stable. And I need 2.0.0 for a bug fix of another package.

> Because analyzer >=2.0.0 depends on meta ^1.7.0 and every version of
> flutter_test from sdk depends on meta 1.3.0, analyzer >=2.0.0 is
> incompatible with flutter_test from sdk. So, because denkschule
> depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and analyzer 2.0.0, version
> solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because myP depends on both
> flutter_test any from sdk and analyzer 2.0.0, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since version 1.7.0 of `package:meta` is probably backward compatible with version 1.3.0, I think that it would be safe to add a [dependency override](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to your `pubspec.yaml` file to force using the newer version:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  meta: ^1.7.0
```

(`package:meta` in particular should be safe since that package just provides annotations for static analysis and shouldn't affect runtime behavior.)

Comment: appears to work! I wouldn't have dared to do this without "clearance". If it should cause issues later on, I will note this here - in case someone else runs into the issue